# Converting sequence of integers in list

Tags: list, split, integer, space

Program receive a sequence from integers, divided spaces
I dont understand how to convert it in list ?

I've try to do this with split method, but it does not help, because i think, it working only with strings

Input:
x = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Output:
list_new = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using

Answer (score 0):

the input can't be like: x = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
it could be something like x = 123456789;
in this case, you would think for example to cascade it to string and then split it as you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

The input you're declaring is a string "1 2 3 4 5 6". So to convert it to List[int] you should split each number and convert it to integer, then add each one to the list